# Python Crash Course Eric Matthes

Tags: python

I am beginner in coding. Working on Chapter 16, I am confused with one of the code.

CODE 1 is from the author:

1.

```
def get_country_code(country_name):
    for name , code in COUNTRIES.items():
        if name == country_name:
            return code
    return None

print(get_country_code('United States'))
```

Prints "us" as code for United States.

Why does the second code not work when else is used in case no match for `country_name`?

2.

```
def get_country_code(country_name):
    for name , code in COUNTRIES.items():
        if name == country_name:
            return code
        else:
            return None

print(get_country_code('United States'))
```

Prints "None".

Would you please help me figure this out?

Comment: it return out of for loop not from function get_country_code()

Comment: change prints None to print(None) last line

Comment: The first function returns `None` only after all countries are examined and no match is found.  The second function returns `None` (thus immediately terminating the function) if the _first_ country does not match.

Comment: thank you @JohnGordon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second code snippet, your function will return on the first time through the loop, every time. Whether you have matched or not.

In the first, you go through the whole loop and then return `None`.

By putting the other return statement inside the loop, if you can match the country, it will return early.

This first option is what it looks like that you want.

Comment: COUNTRIES.get(country_name)

Answer (score 0):

Your second code is running only once . on 1st iteration when if not match with country code in if code move to else and return None .Once return is executed your for loop is getting terminated after returning None .

Answer (score 0):

For those who might have similar questions, in the first code, you're looping through a dictionary of countries and the corresponding country code, if the name of a country in the dictionary matches the name of the country parsed as an argument in the function call, then the corresponding country code will be returned from the dict. In this case, the argument parsed is 'United States' hence the returned value is  "us". This effectively ends the execution of the function, and returns control to the calling function.

In the second code, you loop through the dict of countries and corresponding country codes, if the name of a country matches the parsed argument, the corresponding country code is returned, else None is returned. In this case, None is returned suggesting that the first country in that dictionary is not the parsed argument i.e. 'United States'. Remember, the execution of a function is terminated after it returns a value and the control transferred to the function call. Consider this example below:

```py
def return_statement():
    for i in range(10):
        return i
```

In this example, the first value in the range of numbers is returned and that is 0. After this, the execution of the function ends.
I hope this helps someone else who may have similar questions.